# Нужна помощь в коде

Tags: python, python-2.x, случайные-числа

Как сделать Уникальной каждую строку без повторов слов? Чтоб проверить все варианты словосочетаний из 9 слов.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы `проверить все варианты словосочетаний из 9 слов.`, используйте `itertools`, генерируя **размещения** с помощью `permutations` с параметром `r=9`

```
import itertools
a = list('abcd')
result = ([x for x in itertools.permutations(a, 2)])
print(result)

[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('b', 'a'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'a'),
 ('c', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('d', 'a'), ('d', 'b'), ('d', 'c')]
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам за хороший ответ.) Но Я не знаю где это прописать все в коде, кроме import itertools. Я понимаю что повтор слов и строк абсолютно не возможен по вашему совету. Может вы бы могли вписать команду где она нужна в моем коде? Прошу вас помогите с задачей.

Comment: Я же дал рабочий код. Вместо `a` подставляете свой `CODEWORDS`, вместо 2 - 9.

Comment: Да понятно, что это не ваш код. Есть же сайты для фриланса, туда обращайтесь. Это сайт вопрос-ответ, и на конкретный вопрос я ответил.

Comment: MBo Спасибо Вам за подсказки, это все ценно для меня)  Успехов вам!